# Data class where i need to set values for different fields at different times

Tags: performance, android, kotlin

I am creating a request for an api using below class-

```
class ABCDRequest {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private var name: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("question")
    private var question: String? = null

    @JsonProperty("ans")
    private var ans: String? = null

    fun getName(): String? {
        return name
    }

    fun setName(userName: String?) {
        this.name = userName
    }

    fun getQuestion(): String? {
        return question
    }

    fun setQuestion(ques: String?) {
        this.question = ques
    }

    fun getAns(): String? {
        return ans
    }

    fun setAns(answer: String?) {
        this.ans = answer
    }

}
```

I need both setter and getter methods and i need to set values for different fields at different times(not at time time of creation of object for this class).

Is the above way idle or is there any 1 or few lines code for this in kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Data Class` which automatically generates field accessors, hashCode(), equals(), toString() and other methods. Read [this](https://medium.com/@DarrenAtherton/intro-to-data-classes-in-kotlin-7f956d54365c) for a quick introduction.

```
data class ABCDRequest (
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private var name: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("question")
    private var question: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("ans")
    private var ans: String? = null
)
```

For the official documentation on `Data Class`, head over to this [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html).

Comment: I'm starting to like Kotlin. C# should steal some features from it ;-)

Comment: As wriiten in my question -`i need to set values for different fields at different times(not at time time of creation of object for this class)`.So if i use this way i need to provide all values while creating object of the class in its constructor

Comment: No, you don't need to provide all values at the time of its creation. Use this data class like this: `var request: ABCDRequest = ABCDRequest()` and when you want to access/set/get the values, `request.name = "Android"` or `request.question?.let { showToast(it.value)  }`

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper, could you please inform me of the error that you're facing with? Yes I use data classes similarly to fetch, store and use data in android